# Does boost asio call async handlers sequentially

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, boost-asio

If I start an asio timer and a receive on a separate thread to my main thread can the handlers ever run at the same time? I presume not and the separate thread calls events sequentially even if they are ready at the same time. To call handlers at the same time asio would have to make its own (3rd) thread or even interrupt one handler to run the other. I can't find documentation that says handlers will be called sequentially even though that seems probable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If multiple threads are servicing an `io_service`'s event loop, such as a pool of threads invoking [`io_service::run()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/run.html), then handlers may execute concurrently.  On the other hand, if there is only one thread servicing the `io_service`, then it is ensured that callback handlers will not run concurrently, as Boost.Asio guarantees callback handlers will only execute from within a thread currently calling `io_service::run*()`.  The Boost.Asio [Timer.5 - Synchronising handlers in multithreaded programs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer5.html)  tutorial may provide some more insight on this topic.

Comment: Tanner, thank you for your response I am now happy that my guess was correct. I looked in the tutorial but still couldn't find documentation that a single run in one thread will run handlers sequentially. Could you point me to the text please?

Comment: @Ant The last line of the second paragraph of the [tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer5.html) states: "calling `io_service::run()` from only one thread ensures that callback handlers cannot run concurrently."

Comment: thank you so much. I couldn't see for looking. I am happy now!